# Read pattern from a file, grep only the fist occurrence

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I'm reading a string from file, appliances_list.txt.

appliances_list.txt contains

```
fridge
dryer
ironbox
microwave
```

The file I'm reading is myappliances.txt. Content is

```
I have a fridge
I have another fridge
I have a refridgerator
I have a microwave
I have ironbox at home
I have another microwave
I have a hairdryer
```

I'm using

```
grep -o -m1 -f appliances_list.txt myappliances.txt
```

Output is

`fridge`

My desired output is, first occurrence of each string (exact match)

```
fridge
microwave
ironbox
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, please use the `{}` button in your editor to fix the layout for the data and code samples. Thanks.

Comment: Sure.   Thanks James.

Comment: @jww Shell scripts are still programming.

Comment: @Nandu I'm assuming your real patterns actually have some wildchars that match different things on different lines?

Comment: @o11c - this is not a scripting question. Its a question on using a command.

Comment: @jww so is almost every other question tagged with `grep` or `sed` or a couple dozen other shell commands which are asked and answered daily and just because the OP is using `grep` in an attempt that doesn't do what they want obviously that doesn't mean the right solution will just use `grep` - maybe the solution will require an awk or perl or ruby or python script. The question is absolutely on topic for this site and extremely common in nature.

Comment: @Nandu your question is extremely unclear. Replace the word "pattern" in your question everywhere it occurs with "string" or "regexp" or whatever else you specifically mean at each point and tell us if you want full or partial matches and post sample input/output that contains concrete examples of your data, not, for example, the string "MyAddress" repeated 6 times and include the cases you think will be hard to handle. ie. give us a [mcve] including sample input/output we could thoroughly test a potential solution against.

Comment: @Ed Morton The whole idea is, patterns are in a file (pattern.txt). Take each pattern from the file, search another file (sample.txt) for this pattern, print only the first occurrence of the pattern (exact match). Let me update the example to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes that's obvious but what isn't obvious is what "pattern" means. There are no "pattern"s in text comparisons - you either want to match strings against regexps or strings against strings. The difference between the 2 is vast and the word "pattern" could mean either so you need to edit your question to replace "pattern" with either "regexp" or "string" wherever it occurs so we know which you mean and consequently what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Ed Morton, it's string. I have updated the question.

Comment: Getting close now just say in your question if you're looking for partial or full matches and include examples where the target string is part of another string (e.g. fridge and refridgerator) or appears in the wrong place (e.g. maybe you're trying to match `iron` from your first file as the last field in your second file but `I have an iron fridge` appears in your 2nd file and you would not want `iron` to match that line since it's not talking about an iron). It's always trivial to write scripts that match what you want and MUCH harder to not match what you don't want.

Comment: @Ed Morton, I'm looking for the exact match of string. Updated question.

Comment: Can your appliance names contain spaces, e.g. `convection oven`? If so add that case and, again, if it can occur then add cases where the word from appliances_list.txt appears in the wrong location in `myappliances.txt`, i.e. the word appears but it's not a match due to where it appears (e.g. `I have an iron` vs `I have an iron stove` - presumably `iron` from appliances_list.txt should match the first case but not the second case). Then explain how the matching should occur (i.e. in which position(s) and how to handle spaces).

Comment: @Ed Morton, string can be at any location. Updated question. Appliances will not have spaces.

Comment: OK, I've nominated the question to be re-opened since you've now provided the info that was missing. You can either wait for that to happen (or not!) or ask a new question containing the complete information and that one would almost certainly not get closed and you'd get the answer you were looking for.

Comment: @Ed Morton, I have opened another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next}a[$2]==1{print $2;a[$2]++}' pattern sample
Pattern1
Pattern2
Pattern3
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '           # well, awk
NR==FNR {         # for the first file
    a[$1]=1       # hash each keyword and set it as 1
    next          # next record
}
a[$2]==1 {        # second file, if the word in 2nd column was hashed and 1
    print $2      # output it
    a[$2]++       # and increase its value above 1
}' pattern sample # mind the order
```

Comment: Thanks James. I tried the solution. Nothing was printed :(